# Fail to deploy Django application with standard environment to Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I deployed my Django app last Wednesday and everything was ok. On the next day, I tried to deploy changes, and App Engine ran into an error: `INTERNAL: Internal error encountered.` Also, I ran the deployment command today using the same `app.yml` config and nothing has changed. The same error has occurred.

My `app.yml`:

```
runtime: python37
instance_class: F1
env: standard
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT MyProject.wsgi --timeout 600

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "<project-name>:<region>:<database-name>"

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

Here are the logs:

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.app.deploy] with arguments: [--quiet: "True", --verbosity: "debug", DEPLOYABLES:1: "[u'app.yaml']"]
DEBUG: Loading runtimes experiment config from [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml]
INFO: Reading [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x7f463bc2cd10>]
DEBUG: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/runtime_builders.py", line 269, in _Read
    with contextlib.closing(storage_client.ReadObject(object_)) as f:
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/storage/storage_api.py", line 303, in ReadObject
    object_=object_ref, err=http_exc.HttpException(err)))
BadFileException: Could not read [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x7f463bc2cd10>]. Please retry: HTTPError 404: No such object: runtime-builders/experiments.yaml
DEBUG: Experiment config file could not be read. This error is informational, and does not cause a deployment to fail. Reason: Unable to read the runtimes experiment config: [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml], error: Could not read [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x7f463bc2cd10>]. Please retry: HTTPError 404: No such object: runtime-builders/experiments.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 133, in _ServerSideExperimentEnabled
    runtimes_builder_root)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/runtime_builders.py", line 524, in LoadFromURI
    .format(uri, e))
ExperimentsError: Unable to read the runtimes experiment config: [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml], error: Could not read [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x7f463bc2cd10>]. Please retry: HTTPError 404: No such object: runtime-builders/experiments.yaml
DEBUG: API endpoint: [https://appengine.googleapis.com/], API version: [v1]
Services to deploy:

descriptor:      [/home/runner/work/MyProject/MyProject/app.yaml]
source:          [/home/runner/work/MyProject/MyProject]
target project:  [<project-name>]
target service:  [default]
target version:  [20201018t154518]
target url:      [https://<site-url>]


DEBUG: No bucket specified, retrieving default bucket.
DEBUG: Using bucket [gs://staging.<bucket-name>.appspot.com].
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
INFO: Using ignore file at [/home/runner/work/MyProject/MyProject/.gcloudignore].
DEBUG: Skipping file [README.md]
DEBUG: Skipping file [static]
DEBUG: Skipping file [.github]
DEBUG: Skipping file [tests]
DEBUG: Skipping file [.git]
DEBUG: Skipping file [misc]
DEBUG: Skipping file [static-root]
DEBUG: Skipping upload of [my_file_1.py]
...
DEBUG: Skipping upload of [my_file_n.py]

INFO: Incremental upload skipped 85.92% of data
DEBUG: Uploading 164 files to Google Cloud Storage
DEBUG: Using [16] threads
#============================================================#
#= Uploading 164 files to Google Cloud Storage              =#
#INFO: Uploading [/home/runner/work/MyProject/MyProject/my_file_1.py] to [staging.<project-name>.appspot.com/1373be4811b24b04f2c1f0aaef730bdc76346e4a]
...
#INFO: Uploading [/home/runner/work/MyProject/MyProject/my_file_n.py] to [staging.<project-name>.appspot.com/1373be4811b24b04f2c1f0aaef730bdc76346e4a]

File upload done.
INFO: Manifest: [{...}]

DEBUG: Converted YAML to JSON: "{
  "betaSettings": {
    "cloud_sql_instances": "<project-name>:<region>:<database-name>"
  }, 
  "entrypoint": {
    "shell": "gunicorn -b :$PORT MyProject.wsgi --timeout 600"
  }, 
  "env": "standard", 
  "handlers": [
    {
      "redirectHttpResponseCode": "REDIRECT_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_301", 
      "script": {
        "scriptPath": "auto"
      }, 
      "securityLevel": "SECURE_ALWAYS", 
      "urlRegex": "/.*"
    }
  ], 
  "instanceClass": "F1", 
  "runtime": "python37"
}"
DEBUG: Response returned status 500, retrying
DEBUG: Retrying request to url https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/<project-name>/services/default/versions?alt=json after exception HttpError accessing <https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/<project-name>/services/default/versions?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '500', 'content-length': '109', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Sun, 18 Oct 2020 15:45:29 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'alt-svc': 'h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
>
DEBUG: Response returned status 500, retrying
DEBUG: Retrying request to url https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/<project-name>/services/default/versions?alt=json after exception HttpError accessing <https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/<project-name>/services/default/versions?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '500', 'content-length': '109', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Sun, 18 Oct 2020 15:45:29 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'alt-svc': 'h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
>
DEBUG: Response returned status 500, retrying
DEBUG: Retrying request to url https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/<project-name>/services/default/versions?alt=json after exception HttpError accessing <https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/<project-name>/services/default/versions?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '500', 'content-length': '109', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Sun, 18 Oct 2020 15:45:29 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'alt-svc': 'h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
>
DEBUG: Response returned status 500, retrying
DEBUG: Retrying request to url https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/<project-name>/services/default/versions?alt=json after exception HttpError accessing <https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/<project-name>/services/default/versions?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '500', 'content-length': '109', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Sun, 18 Oct 2020 15:45:29 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'alt-svc': 'h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
>
DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) INTERNAL: Internal error encountered.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 983, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 117, in Run
    default_strategy=flex_image_build_option_default))
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 643, in RunDeploy
    ignore_file=args.ignore_file)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 433, in Deploy
    extra_config_settings)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py", line 172, in DeployService
    extra_config_settings)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py", line 249, in _CreateVersion
    return self.client.apps_services_versions.Create(create_request)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/apis/appengine/v1/appengine_v1_client.py", line 827, in Create
    config, request, global_params=global_params)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 729, in _RunMethod
    http, http_request, **opts)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py", line 346, in MakeRequest
    check_response_func=check_response_func)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py", line 402, in _MakeRequestNoRetry
    check_response_func(response)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/apis.py", line 281, in _CheckResponseForApiEnablement
    http_wrapper.CheckResponse(response)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/gcloud/290.0.1/x64/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py", line 223, in CheckResponse
    raise exceptions.BadStatusCodeError.FromResponse(response)
BadStatusCodeError: HttpError accessing <https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/<project-name>/services/default/versions?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '500', 'content-length': '109', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Sun, 18 Oct 2020 15:46:08 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'alt-svc': 'h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
>
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INTERNAL: Internal error encountered.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you check if you are using the latest gcloud updates by running `gcloud components update` ?

Comment: I ran the deployment using the latest version and I've got this error. Then I tried previous versions (271.0.0 and 390.0.0) but it didn't help. In some time I will post the output of `gcloud components update` because now I have not an opportunity to do it :(

Comment: Hi @YuraLisovskiy could you please take a look at this documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/quickstart#view) and get more details about the error? As it seems, this message is super generic and there isn't much information on exactly what it's causing the issue, so having more details from the Error Report should help.

Comment: Just checked Error Reporting and there is not this error in the list. I've found only runtime errors related to the editing of read-only local files.

Comment: Hi @YuraLisovskiy I would recommend you to reach out to [Google 1:1 support](https://cloud.google.com/support), so they can check further your instance, as this seems to a specific error within your instance.